# Reading string data separated by spaces in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two-column data in a text file, eg as follows.

```
Balkrishna Industries Ltd. Auto Ancillaries 3.54
Aurobindo Pharma Ltd. Pharmaceuticals 3.36
NIIT Technologies Ltd. Software 3.31
Sonata Software Ltd. Software 3.21
```

When I tried to read this in Pandas, I get an error as the space is a delimiter, and the company names are not restricted to a single column. How do I modify my code to separate this data into two columns, one for the name and one for the number?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ["Name", "Fraction"]

print(data)
```

Comment: Can you share the file? I guess that it is tab between the name and fraction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Regex Lookbehind & Lookahead `sep="(?<=\w) (?=\d)"`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="(?<=\w) (?=\d)", names=["Name", "Fraction"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                          Name  Fraction
0  Balkrishna Industries Ltd. Auto Ancillaries      3.54
1        Aurobindo Pharma Ltd. Pharmaceuticals      3.36
2              NIIT Technologies Ltd. Software      3.31
3                Sonata Software Ltd. Software      3.21
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, read the file in as one column (*use a `sep` character that doesn't exist in the file - such as* `|`).

Then use [`Series.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), with `n=1` and `expand=True` arguments, to split the string, on whitespace, from the right, with only 1 partition, returned as a `DataFrame` with 2 columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='|', header=None)

df = df[0].str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)
df.columns = ["Name", "Fraction"]
```

[out]

```
                                          Name     Fraction
0  Balkrishna Industries Ltd. Auto Ancillaries         3.54
1        Aurobindo Pharma Ltd. Pharmaceuticals         3.36
2              NIIT Technologies Ltd. Software         3.31
3                Sonata Software Ltd. Software         3.21
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a "char-space-digit" separator:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.txt", sep="\w\s\d", engine="python", names=["Name", "Fraction"])
print(df)

                                         Name  Fraction
0  Balkrishna Industries Ltd. Auto Ancillarie      0.54
1        Aurobindo Pharma Ltd. Pharmaceutical      0.36
2              NIIT Technologies Ltd. Softwar      0.31
3                Sonata Software Ltd. Softwar      0.21
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read it in as one-column dataframe as this sample:

```
df:
                                               name
0  Balkrishna Industries Ltd. Auto Ancillaries 3.54
1        Aurobindo Pharma Ltd. Pharmaceuticals 3.36
2              NIIT Technologies Ltd. Software 3.31
3                Sonata Software Ltd. Software 3.21
```

After that just call `str.rpartition` on `df.name` and drop the blank column as follows:

```
df.name.str.rpartition().drop(1, 1).set_axis(["Name", "Fraction"], axis=1, inplace=False)

Out[1594]:
                                          Name Fraction
0  Balkrishna Industries Ltd. Auto Ancillaries     3.54
1        Aurobindo Pharma Ltd. Pharmaceuticals     3.36
2              NIIT Technologies Ltd. Software     3.31
3                Sonata Software Ltd. Software     3.21
```